# Non-Linear/Robust Regression in Scala

Tags: java, r, scala, regression

I'm looking for non-linear polynomial regression in Scala/java, which i can use in my scala project.

I explored `scalalab`...it claims it supports regression but i was not able to required function in it to do so.

I also explored `nak`, but it supports only linear regression, same was the case with `apache commons math`.

Basically i am looking for something in scala what `rlm()`[robust regression] does for R.

What are the alternatives ? Please suggest.

Comment: Polynomial regression is actually a linear regression:
a polynomial is a linear combination of monomials.

Comment: i know that...but i dont want to engineer it myself if it's readily available...as i'll have to change logic for creating monomials everytime the degree changes. If it isn't available i'll have to workout multi variable linear regressions of apache commons only....which is fine in worst case.